# How to minimize the number of system calls? in C

Tags: c, copy

How to minimize the number of system calls read() and write() in my code ?

```
int copy(char* entry, char* exit){
    char buf; 
    int in; 
    int out; 

    in = open(entry,O_RDONLY);
    out = open(exit ,O_APPEND|O_WRONLY);
    while(read(in, &buf, 1) != 0){
        write(out, &buf, 1); }

    close(in);
    close(out);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Use a bigger buffer.

Comment: But the file can have a size 50, but can also be a 350. So I do not know how big the buffer set that I minimize the number of calls.

Comment: A buffer can be an arbitrary length. If 1K bytes then it divides by 1000 the number of system calls. Besides `read()` gives you the number of bytes read in case the remaining bytes to read are less than the buffer width.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you enlarge your buffer to for example 256, now write:

```
char buf[256];
int n;
...
while((n=read(in, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0){
    write(out, buf, n);
}
```

This reads, upon every read, a maximum of 256 bytes. `read` returns the number of bytes read, so `n` now has this number, which is what you write out. The last read will be less than 256, so the last write will also be less than 256.